# Labeling inside factors with conditions

Tags: r, label

I am trying to classify ratings for my imported dataset as factors and trying to label the ones less than or equal to 3 as bad and greater than 3 as good

```
 a_reviews$rating <- factor(a_reviews$rating,level = 1:5,ifelse(a_reviews$rating<=3, label= 'Bad', label='Good'))
```

but I get the error

```
Error in ifelse(a_reviews$rating <= 3, label = "Bad", label = "Good") : 
  unused arguments (label = "Bad", label = "Good")
```

Comment: can you post your `a_reviews`?

Comment: You can't have multiple factor levels with the same labels (e.g. 1,2,3 all labelled 'bad').  You could do something like `a_reviews$ratinglabel <- ifelse(a_reviews$rating<=3,"Bad","Good")`

Comment: @AndrewGustar wrap ifelse with as.factor, and post as an answer?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple factor levels with the same labels (e.g. 1,2,3 all labelled 'bad'). You could do something like

```
a_reviews$ratinglabel <- as.factor(ifelse(a_reviews$rating<=3,"Bad","Good"))
```

and work with that.